# Stored procedure to copy only latest records from one table to another

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, sql-insert

I have a situation where my source table  TABLE_A gets frequently updated on hourly basis through some front end consumer app.
I've another reporting table TABLE_B which gets some of its data from TABLE_A.

Initially copying of records which were done manually through insert statement.
Now this needs to be automated where a stored procedure/script runs every 1 hr and copies the records. So when this script does a 2nd run , it should not copy the records which it has already copied in its first run.
Please help me in how I can do this.

TABLE_A:

```
id  date         product    type
11  2020-10-14    abc        T
12  2020-10-16    def        P
- - - - - - - - - -- - - - -- - - - -- - - -- 
13  2020-10-17    ghi        K
14  2020-10-18    klm        L
15  2020-10-19    abc        T
```

TABLE_B

```
id        date              product       type
hadgha     2020-10-14         abc          T
gsggss     2020-10-16         def          P
```

Suppose the script has copied the first 2 records in its first run and after that records 13 / 14 / 15 has been added to TABLE_A. Now in the second run the script should copy the last 3 records from TABLE_A to TABLE_B..

Comment: Why are `id`s of `tableB` different than those in `tableA`?

Comment: What defines duplicates?  `id` or `product`/`type`?

Comment: id of table A and table B are different as these are completely independent different. I need to pull few fields from tableA to tableB which I've shown above. Now think like this - This is Oct. Till Sept the data  I used to get is through csv file which I used to upload in table B using phpMyadmin. Now I have to upload the Oct data and going forward all the coming months data  from this tableA.  This tableA id is PK and auto_incremental. tableB Id field is something different an dnot increment. but TableB has another field id_temp which is incremental.

Comment: Note this tableB id_temp value and tableA id value are different. Like one starts with 1500 and other with 1. But I am open to add any column in tableB to have the solution.

Comment: and so I was thinking on the lines of stored procedure  of having a temp_table which stores cursor data or something like this... I may be completely wrong in my line of thinking and that a simple query can do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tables don't have any duplicate key or any constraints in common.
The stored procedure that is being created has variables to capture the max count id and then updating this max count id on every run.. this way it is ensured that it copies the records that has not been copied in last run.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `id` is a primary key in both tables, you can use `on duplicate key`:

```
insert into table_b values(id, date, product, type)
select id, date, product, type
from table_a
on duplicate key update id = values(id)
```

Basically this attempts to `insert` everything from `table_a` to `table_b`; when an already-existing record is met, the query goes to the `on duplicate key` clause, that performs a "dummy" update (the values are the same already, so that's a no-op: MySQL skips the update).

For this to properly work, I would recommend:

- setting `id` in `table_a` to  `int primary key auto_increment`
- setting `id` in `table_b` to a `int primary key` (not auto increment, since values will always be copied from the other table)

Comment: In my case this will not work as desired . I am explaining why. 
to have yoour solution implemented I created a column in table_b by name id_a. This is not set to auto increment as the values will be copied from tableA - field id.

Current State of tableA
id  date         product    type
11  2020-10-14    abc        T
12  2020-10-16    def        P

13  2020-10-17    def        P
14  2020-10-18    def        P
15  2020-10-19    def        P
16  2020-10-20    def        P

Comment: current state of tableB

id        date              product       type
1a     2020-10-14         abc          T
1b     2020-10-16         def          P 

Requiremnet:
To the script which autoruns every one hour which copies records from tableA from id 13 to 16 in its first run and from id 16 onwards in its next run , and similarly in its subsequent runs. 
Note tableA.id and tableB.id are completely independent and has nothing to take with each other. Also I cannot touch/alter/update the existing records in tableB.

Comment: Solution/Stragey:

I added a column by name id_a in tableB. This will be used to store tableA.id values. 


id        date              product       type  id_a
1a     2020-10-14         abc          T
1b     2020-10-16         def          P 

Now I need to copy the values for records 13/14/15/16 into table B. 
So I ran this script

insert into ext_rev_payment values(id, date, product, type)
select id, date, product, type
from tableA WHERE id >= 13

Comment: This will make bt tableB as below:

id        date              product       type  id_a
1a     2020-10-14         abc          T          NULL/0
1b     2020-10-16         def          P          NULL/0

13  2020-10-17            def          P          13
14  2020-10-18            def          P          14
15  2020-10-19            def          P          15
16  2020-10-20            def          P          16

All good till here.

Comment: Now new records are added to tableA:

id  date         product    type
11  2020-10-14    abc        T
12  2020-10-16    def        P
13  2020-10-17    def        P
14  2020-10-18    def        P
15  2020-10-19    def        P
16  2020-10-20    def        P

17  2020-10-20    def        Y
18  2020-10-21    def        Z
19  2020-10-21    def        I

Comment: now if I run your script 

insert into tableB values(id, date, product, type)
select id, date, product, type
from tableA
on duplicate key update id = values(id_a)

This I think will update all all records of tableB and not only 16 from 16 onwards becaue it will check id_a NULL/0 as well.

SO I think to put WHERE condition so that it should always check from 13 and onwards. 
 
insert into tableB values(id, date, product, type)
select id, date, product, type
from tableA WHERE id_a > 13
on duplicate key update id = values(id_a)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest filtering them out using a subquery and then using `on duplicate key`:

```
insert into table_b values(id, date, product, type)
    select id, date, product, type
    from table_a a
    where a.date = (select max(a2.date) from table_a a2 where a2.type = a.type and a2.product = a.product)
    on duplicate key update id = values(id);
```

This assumes that you have a unique constraint on `table_b(product, type)`.